# How to change breadcrumbs top border?

Tags: webstorm

Its own settings cannot change the color. This seems to be caused by other settings.

[image]

Comment: Same on WebStorm Forums: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360006702940-How-to-change-webstorm-breadcrumbs-top-border-

Answer (score 1):

I have solved.It's setted by Separator line below.

[image]